# [ScatterPlot][Potly][Python] How to have marker of heart shape in scatter plot

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, scatter-plot

[image]
I was looking into the documents but I didn't find a marker with shape of heart.
Is it possible to have markers in scatter plot(plotly) to have markers of the shape of heart as shown in below image?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is to use unicode symbols https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_symbols.asp

To color, pass an array/list to `textfont_color`

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

go.Figure(
    go.Scatter(
        x=np.random.randint(1, 5, 10),
        y=np.random.randint(1, 5, 10),
        mode="text",
        text="♥",
        textfont_size=20,
        textfont_color=np.random.choice(["red","yellow","blue"], 10)
    )
)
```

[image]

### with borders

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randint(1, 5, 10)
y = np.random.randint(1, 5, 10)

fig = go.Figure(
    [
        go.Scatter(
            x=x,
            y=y,
            mode="text",
            text="♥",
            textfont_size=80,
            textfont_color="white",
            textposition="middle center",
        ),
        go.Scatter(
            x=x,
            y=y,
            mode="text",
            text="♥",
            textfont_size=40,
            textfont_color=np.random.choice(["red", "yellow", "blue"], 10),
            textposition="middle center",
        ),
    ]
)
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Appreciate it!!

Comment: How can we change the color of the hearts??

Comment: Like Having different color hearts in single plot

Comment: updated to include how to set color of hearts

Comment: In continuation of above question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71045877/scatteris-it-possible-to-have-points-which-shade-out-in-scatter-plot

Comment: can we have border to this text like white border to heart shape of given colour?

Comment: I don't see a direct way,  have layered traces on top of each other to do this.  have added another section to answer

Comment: Thanks Rob. I was looking into fig.add_annotation but didn't had the luck.