# Is it possible to have points which shade out in scatter plot?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash, scatter-plot

We can plot heart shape and other shape in scatter plot. But is it possible to have a plot where points in plot shades out [in circle] as shown in below image with **text beside it**.

Thanks for your response in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You'll need to add the value to the `plotly.graph_objects.Scatter.text` attribute. I suspect that you have a heart symbol/emoji for the `text` attribute, so have a list of the values you want to put in the text ordered by your preference to match the points, and append the heart symbol to it. Here's an generic example of how it can be done:

```py
import dash
from dash import html, dcc
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

app = dash.Dash()

df = pd.DataFrame([
    np.random.randint(1, 5, 5),
    np.random.randint(1, 5, 5),
    ["text_1", "text_2", "text_3", "text_4", "text_5"]]
).transpose()

df.columns = ["x", "y", "text"]

def add_text_to_heart(st):
    return f"♥ {st}"

df["text"] = df["text"].apply(add_text_to_heart)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(figure=(go.Figure(
    go.Scatter(
        x=df["x"],
        y=df["y"],
        mode="text",
        text=df["text"],
        textfont_size=20,
        textfont_color=np.random.choice(["red","yellow","blue"], 10)
    )
)))
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```

Comment: Thanks. But how to have point which shades out as shown in figure. Like a red dot which is dark at center but fades out at outer boundary.

Comment: Also, here text have black color always but point changes color. Is this feasible